# Providing a password to pdfedit from the console tools

Tags: pdf, command-line

I've searched around and can't find anything so far.

**The Problem**

I need to run `pdfedit` from the command line to flatten some pdf's the command is fairly simple.

```
pdfedit -console Flattener in.pdf out.pdf
```

Now when the pdf has a password associated, it ignores the `-console` and opens up a prompt to input a password.

I noticed that pdfedit offers a scripting interface and I've been trying to find if it's possible to somehow feed it the required password through the `-eval [script]` option. But have failed to turn anything up.

Any insight or ideas would be great.

**Edit**

Still trying to find a simple solution however, I've been digging through the source at this point getting to figure out the structure so currently I'm looking into the least favourable choice of modifying the source.
Any help is still appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So your question is how to pass a password to pdfedit from the commandline instead of a popup?